# TypeError: can't access property "classList", btnMenu is undefined btnMenu

Tags: javascript, html, sass

```
const btnMenu = document.querySelector('#btnMenu')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('open menu');
    if (btnMenu.classList.contains('open')) {
      btnMenu.classList.remove('open')
    } else {
      btnMenu.classList.add('open')
    }
  });
```

what is wrong with this code been tryna wrap my head round it, its to ad the action in which a menu opens but im only doing the animation right now.

Comment: why are you reinventing toggle? `btnMenu.classList.toggle('open');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this way..**

```
const btnMenu=document.querySelector('#btnMenu');

btnMenu.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('open menu');

    if(btnMenu.classList.contains('open')){
    btnMenu.classList.remove('open')    
}
else{
    btnMenu.classList.add('open')
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `btnMenu` is being set to the result of `addEventListener` - which isn't a reference to the button. That method returns `undefined`!

Inside an event listener function `this` will refer to the element:

```
document.querySelector('#btnMenu')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('open menu');
    if (this.classList.contains('open')) {
      this.classList.remove('open')
    } else {
      this.classList.add('open')
    }
  });
```